# Bootstrap Drop Down in IE7,8

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use Boostrap 2.3 , Jquery 2.0 in my application , which require to support IE7,8 as well.

But Bootstrap Dropdown is not opening at all.

```
  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"> </script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.22/jquery-ui.min.js"> </script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/2.3.2/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
```

Example Image :

http://s11.postimg.org/hidydz10j/dd_ie8_bug.png

I have googled and all the links to the issues in Github are broken .

Please help me.

Comment: I think you should implement some hacks for IE7 and IE8 because bootstrap will not work for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery 2.0 **does not** support IE before 9, as mentioned in [the release notes](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/):

> As promised, **this version leaves behind the older Internet Explorer 6, 7, and 8 browsers**. In return it is smaller, faster, and can be used in JavaScript environments where the code needed for old-IE compatibility often causes problems of its own. But don’t worry, the **jQuery team still supports the 1.x branch which does run on IE 6/7/8**.

So either ditch these archaic browsers, or use old versions of libraries that still support it. But remember, there is a reason why more & more companies and websites stop supporting Internet Explorer versions before 9.

Comment: And to expand on this, if you use jQuery 1.9.2 (or whatever the current latest stable 1.x release is) they'll work.

Comment: @ChrisFerdinandi: Well, your comment is not really _expansion_ of my answer, it only _rephrases_ it. The bold part "_jQuery team still supports the 1.x branch which does run on IE 6/7/8_" means that jQuery 1.9.2, 1.10.2 and other recent releases of jQuery 1.x support IE 6+.

Comment: Hi, I have moved to jquery-1.8.3.min.js but still the same issue, dropdown in navbar is not opening